# windows workflow - approval level process

Tags: winforms, workflow-foundation-4

I am planning to write a windows forms application that requires multilevel approval in order to process something. Like
Creator (Requester)
-> 
Review (Reviews the order and escalates to next level)
->
Clerk (first level approval)
-> 
Manager (Final approval)
->
Back to creator

Once Creator/Requester fills out a form and submits, I wanted to start a workflow which automatically fires emails and based on response it sends it to the next level.

- Question: I never worked on Windows workflow, is WF suitable for this type of application? Is there any sample(not exactly like this) available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a process orchestration that WF4 is well suited for. In general I would recommend using an IIS hosed workflow service and let that take care of all processing.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. Do you suggest any sample?